Find all functions such that $f(f(a)) = 2bf(a) + f(a^2-b) - f(b)$
I am studying functional equations from different sources. I have bunch of problems but this one I cannot solve.
I hope someone can give some clues.
Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f(f(a)) = 2bf(a) + f(a^2-b) - f(b)$$
for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

I tried basic substitutions like $P(0,0), P(1,0), P(y,x)$ etc.

I tried also more sophisticated substitution. One example is $a^2-b = f(a)$, so that we can get rid of some parts in equations. Neither of this gives significant results.

The most significant result, I guess, I got from $P(0,0)$ that gives me $f(f(0))=0$ or in other words it means that there exists at least one such "$n$" that $f(n)=0$.
After this I tried to use $P(n,b)$ and $P(a,n)$ substitutions. Doesn't seem it gave me any result.


$P(n,b)$ gives us $f(f(n))=f(n^2-b) + 2bf(n) - f(b)$ or $f(0)=f(n^2-b)-f(b)$
I also notice that  $n^2-b$ is $R$
It seems promising, still I do not see what to do next.

I have read also about injective function, but I do not see how this helps here.


@BrevanEllefsen assuming $f(0)\neq 0$ else we just get that $f$ is even.

@Brevan Ellefsen First I didn't get what you mean by a=0, but now I get. I will try to solve this using your idea and following comments.

What contest is this from?

As you said, if we plug $a=b=0$ we get $f(f(0))=0$. Now let $f(0)=c$. We know that $f(c)=0$.
If we set $a=c$ we get
$$ c=f(0)=f(f(c))=f(c^2-b)-f(b) $$
and now when $b=c^2$
$$ c=f(0)-f(c^2)=c-f(c^2) $$
which means $f(c^2)=0$. Now putting $a=c, \ b=0$ into original equation we get
$$ c=f(c^2)-c $$
so $c$ must equal to $0$ and $f(0)=0.$
If $a=0$ we get $0=f(-b)-f(b)$ so $f$ is an even function.
If $b=0$ we get $f(f(a))=f(a^2)$
If $b=a^2$ we get $f(a^2)=2a^2f(a)-f(a^2)$ which means $f(a^2)=a^2f(a)$
Changing $b$ into $-b$ and rearranging equality (and using previous observations) gives us
$$ a^2f(a)+2bf(a)+f(b)=f(a^2+b)$$
Let $f(1)=d$. Now if $a=1$ we get $ f(b+1)=f(b)+2bd+d$ and if $b=1$ we get $f(a^2+1)=a^2f(a)+2f(a)+d$. Combining these two we get
$$ a^2f(a)+2f(a)+d=f(a^2+1)=f(a^2)+2a^2d+d $$
so $f(a)=da^2$ but since $f(f(a))=f(a^2)$ we have $d^3a^4=da^4$, so $d\in \{-1, 0, 1 \}$ and all three functions $f(x)=x^2, f(x)=0, f(x)=-x^2$ satisfy given equation.

Very nice idea. Chris's solution $g(a^2)=g(a)\implies g=cst$ involves continuity (i.e $g(x)=g(x^{1/{2^n}})\to g(x^0)=g(1)=cst$), but yours does not which is an improvement.

In progress... (Chris found a way in the meantime)
$$P(a,b) ::f(f(a)) = 2bf(a)+f(a^2-b)-f(b)$$

$\begin{array}{ll}
P(0,0) :: f(f(0))=0+f(0)-f(0)=0&\implies f(f(0))=0\\
P(0,b) :: f(f(0))=2bf(0)+f(-b)-f(b)&\implies f(b)-f(-b)=-2bf(0)\\
P(a,0) :: f(f(a)) = 0+f(a^2)-f(0)&\implies f(a^2)=f(f(a))+f(0)\end{array}$
Notice that the last equation forces $f\circ f$ to be even.
And reporting in $P(a,b)$ it also forces $f$ to be even.
Therefore reporting in $P(0,b)$ we get $f(0)=0$ therefore $f(f(a))=f(a^2)$
This equation admits the trivial $x\mapsto x^2$ solution (also solution of the original equation), let's try to prove it is the only one...
$P(a,a^2) :: f(f(a))=2a^2f(a)+f(0)-f(a^2)\implies f(a^2)=a^2f(a)$

As usual let $P(a,b)$ be the statement $f(f(a))=2bf(a)+f\left(a^2-b\right)-f(b)$.
From $P(1,1)$, we have $f(f(1))=f(1)+f(0)$.
From $P\left(1,\frac12\right)$, $f(f(1))=f(1)$ so that $f(0)=0$.
$P(0,b)$ gives $f(b)=f(-b)$ - ie $f$ is even.
$P(a,0)$ gives $f(f(a))=f(a^2)$ and $P\left(a,a^2\right)$ that $f(f(a))=2a^2 f(a)-f(a^2)$. Combining these,
$$f(a^2)=a^2 f(a)$$
If we let $f(a)=a^2 g(a)$, this becomes
$$g(a^2)=g(a)$$
with solution $g(a)=c$ for some constant $c$; so $f(a)=ca^2$ (this step needs to be proved! It'll depend on any conditions in the original problem). Substituting into the original equation,
$$c^3 a^4 = 2bca^2+c\left(a^2-b\right)^2-cb^2$$
which simplifies to $c^3=c$; so solutions are $f(a)=-a^2$, $f(a)=0$ and $f(a)=a^2$.

Nice substitution $f(a)=a^2g(a)$

Thanks - the nicer one was in my workings, $f(a)=a^k g(a)$

But what if $g$ is not a constant function? Equation $g(a)=g(a^2)$ has also other solutions

Here I would like to sketch another similar way showing that the only possibile functions are $f(x)=x^2,0,-x^2$.
Use $a=0$ to obtain
$$ f(f(0))=2xf(0)+f(-x)-f(x) \implies f(-x)-f(x)=-2xf(0)+f(f(0)).$$
However, $g(x):=f(-x)-f(x)$ is an odd function, so that the line $-2xf(0)+f(f(0))$ has to be an odd function too:
$$2xf(0)+f(f(0))=-(-2xf(0)+f(f(0))) \implies f(f(0))=0.$$
Thus
$$f(-x)-f(x)=-2xf(0).$$
Moreover $f(f(x))=f(x^2)-f(0)$ if you use $b=0$. Instead if you consider $b=x^2$ then
$$ f(f(x))=2x^2f(x)+f(0)-f(x^2) \implies f(f(x))=2x^2f(x)-f(f(x)) \implies f(f(x))=x^2f(x).$$
Thus
$$f(x^2)-f(0)=x^2f(x) \implies f(x^2)-x^2f(x)=f(0) $$
and if we compute this equation for $x=1$ we obtain $f(0)=0$ so that $f$ is even. Hence we just need to find $f$ on $(0,+\infty)$.
We observe that if $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)\neq 0$ then by $f(f(x))=x^2f(x)$ we obtain either $\alpha=\beta$ of $\alpha=-\beta$. But then from
$$ f(f(x))=f(x^2)$$
we obtain that either $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=x^2$ of $f(x)=-x^2$. Thus we obtain the following possibile functions:
Let fix $A, B\subseteq \mathbb R$ disjoints subsets, and define
$$f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R, \qquad x\mapsto \begin{cases}x^2 \quad if \ x\in A \\ 0 \ \ \ if  \ x\in B \\  -x^2  \ if \ x\notin A\cup B\end{cases}.$$
It remains to understand the structure of $A$ and $B$ for which $f$ satisfies our equation.
Without lost of generality we can suppose $B$ contains $0$, so $0\notin A$.
We will use several times the following equation:
$$ a^2f(a)=f(f(a))=2bf(a)+f(a^2-b)-f(b) \implies f(a^2-b)=(a^2-2b)f(a)+f(b)$$
Let us assume $A$ is empty. If $B$ is the entire $\mathbb R$, then the solution is $f(x)=0$. Thus let us suppose $B\neq \mathbb R$.
Let us take $b\in B$ and $a\notin B$. Then either $a^2-b\in B$ or $a^2-b\notin B$. In the first case
$$0=f(a^2-b)=(a^2-2b)(-a^2)+0\implies a^2=2b.$$
In the second case we have
$$-(a^2-b)^2=f(a^2-b)=(a^2-2b)(-a^2)+0 \implies -b^2=0 \implies b=0.$$
However, we also have $-b\in B$ since $f(-b)=f(b)=0$, so using the same computation as above (with the same value $a$), then we would have either $-b=0$ or $2(-b)=a^2=2b$ so that $b=0$. We have proved $B=\{0\}$, and so the function $f$ is $f(x)=-x^2$.
Now let us consider the case $A$ is nonempty.
Let us prove that $A\cup B = \mathbb R$.
By contradiction, let us fix  $b\notin A\cup B$ and consider $a\in A$. Then $a^2-b\in A$ or $a^2-b\in B$ or $a^2-b\notin A\cup B$. In the first case we have
$$ (a^2-b)^2=(a^2-2b)a^2-b^2 \implies 2b^2=0 \implies b=0,$$
a contradiction.
Instead, in the second case we have
$$ 0=(a^2-2b)a^2-b^2 \implies (a^2-b)^2=2b^2 \implies a^2=(1\pm \sqrt{2})b.$$
Instead, in the third case we have
$$ -(a^2-b)^2=(a^2-2b)a^2-b^2 \implies 2a^4-4a^2b=0 \implies a^2=2b.$$
We note that also $-b\notin A\cup B$ because $f(-b)=f(b)=-b^2=-(-b)^2$. This means that a similar computation as above (using the same value $a$) holds, and so we have either $a^2=(1\pm \sqrt{2})(-b)$ or $a^2=-2b$. This gives three possible equations in $b$:
$$ (1\pm \sqrt{2})(-b)=a^2=(1\pm \sqrt{2})b \qquad 2b=a^2=-2b \qquad 2b=a^2=(1\pm \sqrt{2})(-b)$$
forcing $b$ being equal to zero, which is a contradiction. Thus, we proved $A\cup B=\mathbb R$.
Now let us take $b\in B$ and $a\in A$. Then either $a^2-b\in A$ or $a^2-b\in B$. In the first case we have
$$ (a^2-b)^2=(a^2-2b)a^2 \implies b^2=0 \implies b=0.$$
In the second case
$$  0=(a^2-2b)a^2\implies a^2-2b=0 \implies a^2=2b.$$
However, also $-b\in B$ since $f(-b)=f(b)=0$ and using the same $a$ as above we would get either $-b=0$ or $2(-b)=a^2=2b$ so that $b=0$. In any case $b=0$ and we have proved $B=\{0\}$.
Thus the function we obtain is exactly $f(x)=x^2$.
Thus, at the end of the story, the functions satisfying your equation are only $f(x)=x^2, 0, -x^2$.
Let me know if you agree with my reasoning.
